# Merging Attributes of points into polygon using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, attribute-joins, intersect

I am using ArcMap 10.

I have points layer which the attribute looks like this:

```
FID Shape ID   Lat       Long
0   Point 2065 -5.51666  106.48333
1   Point 2319 21.93333  120.73366
```

I also have polygons layer :

```
FID Shape ID   
0   Polygon 0  
1   Polygon 0
```

How could I join both attribute file so that it become

```
FID Shape ID   Lat       Long          FID2    Shape

0   Point 2065 -5.51666  106.48333     1       Polygon
1   Point 2319 21.93333  120.73366     1       Polygon
2   Point 2304 22.93333  129.73366     3       Polygon
```

The actual case is, there are points that fall within one polygon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this classic point-in-polygon overlay operation is best handled using the [Intersect_analysis](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) tool wich:

> Computes a geometric intersection of the input features.

If you input a feature class or shapefile of points, and another with polygons, then the output is any points falling within a polygon have the ID (and optionally attributes) of that polygon added to then end of its attribute table.