# Adding column to attribute table indicating polygon each data point is in using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-pro, vector, intersect

I am working on a project linking ideas in Geology and Ecology.

I currently have a map showing the geology of an area (polygon layer), with a points layer on top indicating the locations of data collection.

I have added an empty column to the attributes table for the points layer (`geology_where_captured`) and would like to know if there's a way - using arcpy -  to fill in this column with the name or id of the geology that each data point is sitting within?

I have looked into the `SummarizeWithin` function but when I try to use this (I am using ArcMap 10.7.1 on my home computer) I get an error saying the object has no attribute?

I'm pretty new to Python.

I wrote this small bit of code following advice from https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/geoanalytics-desktop/summarize-within.htm

and

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/summarize-within.htm

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:\Users\User\Documents\University\4th Year Project\Data\mydata_arcgisOnline/XYLEMUR_DATA_AMBATOVY2.dbf'
summarizedLayer = "XYLEMUR_DATA_AMBATOVY2"
summaryPolys = "Geology"
arcpy.SummarizeWithin_analysis(summarizedLayer, summaryPolys, 'geology_where_captured')
```

> Runtime error Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
> line 1, in  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
> 'SummarizeWithin_analysis'

No joy! (I'm new to this)

Answer (score 1):

I think this classic point-in-polygon overlay operation is best handled using the [Intersect_analysis](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm) tool wich:

> Computes a geometric intersection of the input features.

If you input a feature class or shapefile of points, and another with polygons, then the output is any points falling within a polygon have the ID (and optionally attributes) of that polygon added to then end of its attribute table.

If you are using ArcMap rather than ArcGIS Pro then the answer is basically the same - see [Merging Attributes of points into polygon using ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/59383/115)